# Is there a way to add source to an svg element

Tags: html, svg

I am lookings for something like:

`<img src="./img.svg"/>`

but with an **svg** element.

This is not working:

`<svg src="./img.svg"></svg>`

EDIT:

The problem is that I have two cases, in first I have a path to an svg and in the second I have a content of an svg in a string. I want to use the same wrapper element for both of them for easier styling instead of using both img and svg elements. Is there a way to use either img or svg element for both of them?

Comment: @RobertLongson I have 2 cases, in first I have a path to an svg and in the second I have a content of an svg in a string. I want to use the same wrapper element for both of them for easier styling instead of using both img and svg elements.

Comment: @RobertLongson that looks to be a solution to my problem, I will update the question and will accept you if you post an answer with img tag using data uri with svg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An `<img>` tag can point to an external file but it can also point to [a data URI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme#SVG).

A data URI is merely an image as a String encoded either in base64 or as a URI (which is almost a string except you need to encode # characters as %23). Basically it would look like this...

```
<img src='data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg ... > ... </svg>'>
```

Answer (score 5):

SVGs do not use sources because they contain graphical information within the tag rather than referencing a file. This code:

```
<svg src="./img.svg"></svg>
```

is redundant because you are referencing an SVG file with an SVG tag so it will not render in HTML. You should use < img > tags with .svg files for the source OR convert your SVGs to < svg > tags that include the graphics information.

If you scale the < img > tag with CSS it will behave like an SVG. I primarily use this format:

```
<img src="./img.svg"></img>
```

if I am just resizing images. I would use < svg > if you want to do styling specific to the vector of the image (color, path, etc.)

https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_svg.asp

Answer (score 1):

```
<image xlink:href="./img.svg" width="..." height="..." />
```

`width` and `height` must be set, svg has no notion of an intrinsic size. For XML conformance, do not forget to declare the `xlink` namespace:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" ... >
```

Comment: I don't think you are answering the question, I'm looking for an svg tag with source and not image tag

Comment: @patotoma Because your question is unclear, what's an svg element supposed to do that an img cannot. You're fixated on that instead of explaining the problem.

Comment: @RobertLongson you are right, I will update my question to explain my problem rather than look for a solution